# C# Text File upload and download issue

Tags: c#, upload, line

Okay so I have an application which uploads a text file to a web server and all works fine.
However, a line magically appears on the text file when it is downloaded

example:

```
textfile contains = Hello World

downloaded textfile contains =                //notice the blank line here
                      Hello World
```

Normally this wouldnt be a problem as I would just create a temp file and delete the line.

However, as the text file contains encrypted data and if I create a new temp file to delete the line it completely messes with the encrypted text and creates
"Bad Data" and "length of data to decrypt is invalid" errors.

Im almost 100% sure its not my encryption algorithm as the text files are output before they are uploaded and it works fine on the non uploaded text files.

If you guys could help me that would be awesome. Any work around will do (no matter how horrible / nasty it is).

Comment: There's a bug in your code somewhere. That's all we can really say at the moment, as you haven't provided any code. I'm wary of a text file containing encrypted data though... raw encrypted data is usually arbitrary binary data, so you shouldn't be treating it as text. Are you using base64 or something similar?

Comment: Im using DES file encryption from the using System.Security.Cryptography;

Comment: Perhaps your encryption algorithm is padding data to get the next bytes, so you are getting null terminated strings. Block ciphers always add padding to your plaintext to get the next full block size before encryption. Try loading your text file on the webserver in a byte array and see if last few bytes are '\0'

Comment: Im pretty sure its not anything to do with my encryption

Answer (score 0):

Does the server and client run the same family operating system? I'm thinking that this may be due to newline sequence differences, and uploading and downloading in different modes (text/binary).

If the data is encrypted or cryptographically signed, you want to do everything you can to make sure the transfers are done in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons something like this can happen.

1. You are making some changes on upload(like parsing the text and some amount of data manipulation,where you introduce this line)
2. You are readingthe file and manipulating it before you download it...

Check both the code and post some samples if you are actually manipulating it. I have uploaded files using c# and it works fine.

You should check [Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) for a simple upload application...It is straight forward.

Comment: My upload class adds headers and footers as its multipart/formdata upload, could this be the problem?

Comment: @Donald - You would have to post the code in order for anyone to answer that question.

Comment: The upload code im using is similar to: codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx just modified to fit my own uses

Comment: @Donald: You should not be adding any headers of your own...adding enctype="multipart/form-data" should do it during upload...What exactly are u doing during download ?

Comment: using a browser, i have a table displaying all the files uploaded, it has a link to download the text file, i click that and it just downloads it

Comment: @Donald : post the code block which is hit when you click on download of any of these file links.(Post it as part of your question.)

Answer (score 0):

What does the download code look like?

Making a wild guess: you are `Response.Write()`ing the text, without a `Response.Clear()` to clear any "aspx text". Plus you need that code to end on a `Response.End()` to prevent further additions to the text.

Comment: Im not using any download code, just saving the textfile straight from the webserver

Comment: So you are using a normal link to a file on the server. I take it that that file doesn't have that extra line (if you access it through the filesystem instead of that link)?

Comment: It does if i access it through the web filesystem, guessing it maybe from the upload then

Comment: The upload code im using is similar to:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/uploadfileex.aspx
just modified to fit my own uses

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your encryption algorithm is appending your text with null terminated string.

Try loading the text file on you webserver in a byte array and see if last byte is '\0'.